# Why can't I check if includes or extract array from fetched json response?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, async-await, es6-promise

Lately I've started some practices with API (so promises). For unknown reasons I can't extract or even check if the value from input match with any if array indexes received from the fetched url.

In HTML I have an input element:

```
<input class='btn'type="text" name="keyword" value='' id="keyword" placeholder="Find by related word..">
```

..represented in js with variable searchedKeyword.

```
const searchedKeyword = document.querySelector('#keyword');
const apiEndpointCategories = 'https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/categories';
```

This line only checks if searchedKeyword is empty.

```
const isEmpty = () =>{
    searchedKeyword.value==''?console.log('Empty - try categories:'):console.log('Not empty');
}

async function getCategories(){

try{
    
const response = await fetch(apiEndpointCategories);
    if(!response.ok){
        alert('Oops, try again!');
        throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    const json = await response.json();
    
    if(!isEmpty()){
        console.log(json);
        console.log(searchedKeyword.value);
}
    else if(json.includes(searchedKeyword.value)){
        console.log('Cool');
         }
}
   catch(err){
        console.log(err);
            return err.
            summonAlert();
        }
    }
```

.. SO. Problem occurs with 'else if(json.includes(searchedKeyword.value))'.
when consol.log(json) - It shows the demanded array, however -  method include() does not work. Is it because json even if it's object, is still represented in pending promise status?

Thanks in advance! I'm back after a long break, so please - don't spare me :) Cheers!

Comment: Could you show what the json looks like and what you are trying to check with includes?

Comment: `isEmpty()` always returns `undefined`. Your `if(json.includes(searchedKeyword.value))` is never even executed.

Comment: Sure, json:[
    "animal",
    "career",
    "celebrity",
    "dev",
    "explicit",
    "fashion",
    "food",
    "history",
    "money",
    "movie",
    "music",
    "political",
    "religion",
    "science",
    "sport",
    "travel"
],

Comment: With includes I'm trying to check if json has any index that contains a value from searchedKeyword variable (input)

Comment: @Bergi Indeed, isEmpty() return undefined, but does it has to return anything to simply log in console if it's empty or not? Also, it's not excecuted if the word in searchedKeyword.value does not match with any of json's array. So if the value was there, it should be excecuted right? Thanks a lot for rply!

Comment: "*it's not excecuted if the word in searchedKeyword.value does not match with any of json's array*" - no, you got that backwards. Your code is `if(!isEmpty()){…} else if(json.includes(searchedKeyword.value)){…}`, which evaluates as `if (!undefined) {…}` and never goes into the `else`.